# l-value and r-value, stack and heap

Tags: java

I am a high school student learning Java (in BlueJ environment).

**Context**

My book, while discussing pass by value and pass by reference mechanisms, uses the terms, stack and heap and also states that each unit in the memory (also known as variable) has a **name**, **l-value** and **r-value** where **l** stands for 'locator' or 'location' and **r** stands for 'read'. The name is used to identify the unit, the l-value stores the address of the unit and the r-value stores the actual value of the unit. In case of primitive datatypes, it store the actual value while in case of reference datatypes it store the address of the reference datatype which refers or points to it. When a function with parameters is called, the r-value of the actual parameters are copied into the r-value of the actual parameter. In case of primitive datatypes the actual value is copied while in case of reference datatypes the reference address is copied due to which, in the former case there is no change in the actual values while in the latter case there is change in the actual values.

**My Questions**

Now, i decided to learn more about this on the Internet. I found that the discussions on the Internet are not in conformity to my book. There l-value and r-value are said to be the value to the left hand side and the right hand side respectively of the assignment sign. I am confused.

What is the actual meaning of l-value and r-value and what does my book mean by stack, heap (I want a simple and easy to understand answer) and unit of memory. I found many questions on this site dealing with stack and heap but could not understand the answers there as they were very technical and as such i do not have so much of a technical knowledge. Also i would like to know where i can learn more about this

Here are the pages from my textbook:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide links or exerts from the said "discussions on the internet"?

Comment: Java doesn't really have a concept of lvalues and rvalues. The only mention of them in the language spec is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html), where it says "A variable (§4.12) (in C, this would be called an lvalue)". An rvalue is basically just an expression which isn't a variable, meaning you can't assign a value to it (it's the "right-hand side" of an assignment).

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) article may be of help. As for stack vs. heap, unfortunately I don't think they can be explained without getting technical. At least not in any way that explains their relation to variables.

Comment: Your book seems to be saying some very strange things. Can you provide what the book actually says? Rather than your interpretation of it? Also a proper citation of the book, so we can avoid it?

Comment: @CKing, http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c

Comment: @EJP, I have uploaded the scanned version of the pages from my textbook.

Answer (score 5):

1. When the terms `l-value` and `r-value` were first coined, l and r
   indeed meant left and right. That is, l-value originally meant left
   hand side of the assignment and r-value meant right hand side of the
   assignment. However, later on, they were revised to indicate
   'locator' and 'read' respectively as your book suggests. The reason
   was that programming languages like C have many operators (e.g.
   address of operator `&`) where the operand that appears to the right
   hand side of the operator is still an l-value.
2. `stack` and `heap` are areas in the memory. Stack is used to store
   local variables and function calls. Heap is used to store `objects`.
   Heap is shared by all threads of your application while stack is
   assigned to each thread.

Comment: Can we say that heap stores all the reference datatypes while stack stores  all the primitive datatypes?

Comment: @MrAP No. Consider objects that contain primitive members.

Comment: @MrAP, as EJP says if primitives are declared as instance variables, they will obviously be stored where the wrapping object is stored which is in heap. However if primitives are declared in a method body, they will be stoered in stack.

Comment: Can you tell me what into what topic do stack and heap fall into (i guess something related to memory like memory structure).

Comment: They should fall into "Memory Management and Allocation" in books. Why is it important though?

Answer (score 2):

Stack and heap:

Stack

The stack is simply a specific range of memory which each program starts with. Every program has a stack and when that programming is running, the CPU actually stores a pointer to 1. where the 'top' of the stack is.
When a function is called, code (produced by a compiler) writes values (copies of parameters, and also the return address of the code that called the function) to the point in memory which is referred to by this stack pointer (SP). It then modifies the SP to point a bit further along, to the point after the parameters.

When your function returns, it writes the return value to the point in memory pointed to by the SP, and then Jumps the code execution back to the code that called the function. That code then copies the return value from the SP location, and decrements the SP.

This area is called a stack because the program copies values onto it when either 1. you declare local variables Or 2. You call functions with parameters.
And then it 'pops' the parameters and local variables off when returning from a function.

(This is how it works in theory. In practice, the compiler will instead write instructions to copy the values to CPU registers instead, where it can. And also the return value).

Heap

The heap simply refers to all other memory which is allocated by the program, usually by a system call (brk in linux) (called by malloc in C).  A program can have many chunks of memory which it has asked the operating system to allocate to it. These chunks of memory (as a whole) are called the heap.

In java:

- when you use the 'new' keyword, what it does is give you back a pointer to some memory which it asked the operating system to give it.
- when you declare a variable not using new, what the compiled code will do is simply use the existing memory at the top of the Stack memory area, and then change the stack pointer.

When you use a pointer variable and assign it an object you create with new ExampleObject(), you are actually doing both things.  In this case the pointer (reference) variable will be created at the Stack Pointer location. Then the Stack Pointer is moved (added to by 8 bytes, the size of the pointer value), then the new() function will obtain the new memory reference from the heap area and then the value of that reference will be copied into the local pointer variable.

In practice a language like Java when it is executing a program, starts with a certain size stack and a certain size of memory (called heap) already allocated to it by the operating system and will only ask for more memory when it is running out of space

It would be worth your time to read on how CPUs work, in particular how they have Registers which store values, and one of them is the Stack Pointer.  Also how they perform additions and subtractions. This is important because they do not (usually) for example when Adding,   add a number from referenced address in memory to a number in another referenced address. If you look at Assembly instructions (similar to java byte code) What they do more often is more like:

For example a function   int addnum(int a, int b) {return a+b;}
  a.  Load the number from SP ie where the SP is pointing, into Register 1

b. Load the number from just before where the SP is pointing (SP-1) into register 2

c. Call Add CPU instruction, which stores the result in register R3
  d. Copy the R3 value to SP+1

Which might look like

Calling code like this: (note, these are made up example CPU instructions - they are different for each CPU and Java has its own bytecode which is similar. I'm just using for example STORESP => write to stack, LOADSP => load from stack pointer)

```
int x;
x =  addnum(9,6);

INCSP  +1   #allocate x at location SP and increment SP by 1

# start function call
# make 3 spaces,   for a, b, and b and return value
INCSP   +3       #add 3 to SP register
STORESP 9,0           # copy 9 value  to SP-0
STORESP 6,-1         # copy 6 value  to SP-1

JUMP addnum    # jump to executing the function code
```

Then, the function itself

```
LOADSP,0,R1       #copy from SP-0 (a) into reg 1
LOADSP,-1,R2     #copy from SP-1(b) into reg 2
ADDREG,R1,R2,R3 # add reg1 reg2 and store in R3

STORESP,R3,-2        #save the result to SP-2
RETURN
```

Then calling function again:
Stores the result in x (copy SP-2) (to SP-3)

```
LOADSP,-2,R1
STORESP,R1,-3
```

Now the function call is done. So throw away the space allocated on the stack for a and b and the return value
(By decrementing SP by 3)

```
ADDSP -3
```

And now the result, is in 'x'

Of course this is much simplified and not accurate but is only for an example to help understand.

But if you can look at how these low level things work, just to do something basic like add two numbers,  then it will help you to understand "where" and "how" parameters are passed in functions,   and exactly how important the stack concept is

Good luck